# Poison Dart Timing

Tags: descent

The overlord has access to a card called Poison Dart (or Poison Dart Trap) that can be played  whenever a hero opens a door or searches.

When a hero searches, does this card get played before they reveal an item from the search deck or after?

It is important as the overlord may decide not to play the Poison Dart card if the player got an item that can immediately discard the poison condition (such as Curse Doll).

Answer (score 1):

'Search' or 'Open door' action should be finished before 'Poison Dart' effects apply.
So, whenever the card was played, hero will receive his item, even if he/she knocked out because of OL card's effect

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thanks for your answer! I think this answer could be significantly improved with a citation that backs it up - from the rulebook, an online FAQ, etc. You're probably right, but it always helps if you can prove it to us!